# how to stream a dvr video using rtsp in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i am working on an application that will play the video from a CCTV camera through DVR.DVR only support RTSP.Still i did not find any clue.we use ozeki camera sdk in desktop application but ozeki sdk's .dll file is not competible in windows phone 8.i need your help guyz.